# Regular Expression for Canadian Postal Code to also allow for lowercase letters or a dash after the first three characters

Tags: .net, regex

```
^[ABCEGHJ-NPRSTVXY]{1}[0-9]{1}[ABCEGHJ-NPRSTV-Z]{1}[ ]?[0-9]{1}[ABCEGHJ-NPRSTV-Z]{1}[0-9]{1}$
```

I would like to add lower case characters to this regex (currently only capital letters are allowed).  I would also like the separator in the middle: '[ ]?' to also allow for a dash (currently allows a space or no space).  How do I ammend the above regex to account for these possible variations.  Language being used is .net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the regular expression constructor, pass the [`RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` flag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx).

For the second requirement, change `[ ]?` to `[ -]?`.

Summary:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"^[ABCEGHJ-NPRSTVXY]{1}[0-9]{1}[ABCEGHJ-NPRSTV-Z]{1}[ -]?[0-9]{1}[ABCEGHJ-NPRSTV-Z]{1}[0-9]{1}$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: Any idea how to added the regexoptions to a data attribute?  I'm using model validation in asp.net mvc:[RegularExpression("^[ABCEGHJ-NPRSTVXY]{1}[0-9]{1}[ABCEGHJ-NPRSTV-Z]{1}[ ]?[0-9]{1}[ABCEGHJ-NPRSTV-Z]{1}[0-9]{1}$", ErrorMessageResourceName = "Invalid_Postal_Code")]

Comment: @FiveTools Just put `(?i)` at the very start of your regular expression right before `^`.